# Display:none Property not working on responsive website

Tags: html, css, containers, responsive, display

I#m struggling with an media query issue.

In the PROJECTS section I want 3 Cards displayed, the way I want do do this is to HIDE card 4 on DESKTOP.

When on Mobile, I want the second (Alias Photography) card to appear FIRST therefore I want to hide card 1.

On small screens, so anything below 575px, I have set card-1 to property display:none. THIS WORKS

But when i scale up to anything larger than 575px, The display:none property on card-4 DOESNT work, and I think it wont work.

Please can someone inspect my code on my website to see why this might be happening? below is the link to my website I'm making currently.

[www.oliver-stott.co.uk](http://www.oliver-stott.co.uk)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to go off-site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building website with dreamweaver I had the same problem. I fixed it when I noticed that desktop version inherits styles from mobile version. So if you give a certain elemen display:none; in the styles for mobile phones and you want it to show on the desktop you have to change the style in desktop to display:block. And the other way around if you want something to show on mobile and not show on desktop. Hope I was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this one, so I found that my card was automatically set to dieplay:block on the css reset.

this means that the display:none; wouldn't override the display:block property.

A simple fix (not ideal but will work for now) is to set the following CSS on the element you want to hide.

```
.card{                         //This was the CSS applied to ALL cards
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.card-4{                      // This is the CSS applied to card 4
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

On your fourth card, try use `d-sm-block d-md-none`, like this:

```
<div class="card col-sm-8 col-md-3 m-3 d-sm-block d-md-none">
...
</div>
```

Let me know if it works as intended